# Is there any generically defined annotations for giving descriptions to members?

Tags: java

I'm looking for an annotation that may be available in any common library such as commons-lang that provides a way to give human readable descriptions to members, such as:

```
@Display(name = "Execute Member",
         description = "Does stuff that things like")
public void doStuff() {
}
```

This would be similar to the [DisplayAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.95).aspx) annotation in C#.

There are no [Predefined Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) that fit the bill.

Comment: And what could that annotation do, which JavaDoc for this method can't? Or where is this description displayed? The C# documentation is quite clear for me (never used this language).

Comment: Javadoc is not available in compiled class files, and I will not be providing it with the application. The goal is to annotate `@RequestMapping` spring-mvc methods for usage auditing.